# Реализация выборки с интерполяцией из 2-мерной таблицы методами JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vba

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать выборку с интерполяцией из 2-мерной таблицы методами JavaScript?

В VBA (MS Execel) создана функция,

*

```
Public Function INTERPOL1D(Value, Value_Vector As Range, Function_Vector As Range)
'Структура данных
Dim v, X, Y
Dim cnt, i, pos
Dim x1, x2, y1, y2
'Инициализация (зачитка и проверка)
cnt = Value_Vector.Cells.Count
v = Value
ReDim X(1 To cnt): ReDim Y(1 To cnt)
For i = 1 To cnt
    X(i) = Value_Vector.Cells(i).Value
    Y(i) = Function_Vector.Cells(i).Value
Next
'Основной блок
If X(1) < X(2) Then
        For i = 1 To cnt 'Step 1
            If X(i) >= v Then 'Нашел верхнюю границу
                If i = 1 Then 'Попали в нижнюю границу
                    x1 = X(i): x2 = X(i + 1): y1 = Y(i): y2 = Y(i + 1)
                Else
                    x1 = X(i - 1): x2 = X(i): y1 = Y(i - 1): y2 = Y(i)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
ElseIf X(1) > X(2) Then
        For i = 1 To cnt 'Step 1
            If X(i) <= v Then 'Нашел верхнюю границу
                If i = 1 Then 'Попали в нижнюю границу
                    x1 = X(i): x2 = X(i + 1): y1 = Y(i): y2 = Y(i + 1)
                Else
                    x1 = X(i - 1): x2 = X(i): y1 = Y(i - 1): y2 = Y(i)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
End If
'Вывод
INTERPOL1D = y2 - ((y2 - y1) * (x2 - v)) / (x2 - x1)
End Function
```

*

которая по заданному значению, находит в исходном столбце/строке соответствующее значение, а затем осуществляет выборку по порядковому номеру значения из требуемого столбца/строки.
Возможно ли что-то подобное создать на JS? И как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно. Это линейная интерполяция Вот пример

```
function linearInterpolate(xData, yData, value){

     i=0;
     size=xData.length;
     if ( x >= xData[size - 2] )                                            
       {
          i = size - 2;
       }
       else
       {
          while ( value > xData[i+1] ) i++;
       }
       var xL = xData[i];
       var yL = yData[i];
       var xR = xData[i+1];
       var yR = yData[i+1];  
       var dydx = ( yR - yL ) / ( xR - xL );                                

       return yL + dydx * ( value - xL );   


    }

    xx=1.5;
    x=[1,2,3];
    y=[3,2,1];
    document.write(linearInterpolate(x,y,xx));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Всё работает отлично!